# firefox doesn't show background image unless I float

Tags: html, css, firefox

This page shows correctly in chromium. In firefox (8) it hides the one image that is a background of a div (should show 6 pictures). It is a hover sprite if that helps... (look at the source)

[dl.dropbox.com/u/6068827/website/index.htm](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6068827/website/index.htm)

If I add:

```
float: left;
```

It works... but why? and is there a cleaner fix?

p.s. I'm on linux and currently don't have access to a windows machine...

Comment: I see it ok in chrome (windows). but you try adding width and height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put background image on an image. While it will work, I don't think that's what you intended.
Either change `img` to `div` (adding width and height) or put that background image in src instead.
 Also you don't close img tag with `</img>` rather it's self closing tag so: `<img class="class" src="path/to/img"/>`.